# LaTeX-Box does not define :Latexmk

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-latex-box

The LaTeX-Box plugin is supposed to define the command `:Latexmk`, but it doesn't!  Am I missing something obvious?

(The reason I'm trying to run latexmk from vim is that I want to use the quickfix list.  If anyone does this without a plugin, please let me know how.)

Comment: Is it just `Latexmk` that's not defined, or are other commands not defined either? How did you install it?

Comment: @muru, not sure, I don't use any other commands from it. I installed it with vim-plug. … I just confirmed that omni-completion works. Help files are installed too, so it isn't that it simply didn't install. In case it might make a difference, I'm running nvim in a mac terminal.

Comment: On my system `:Latexmk` is available only when I'm editing a `*.latex` file, maybe you tried to use the command on another type of file?

Comment: Latexmk available here too.

Comment: @statox, I see, that must be it. I call my latex files *.tex.

Comment: @Lawrence: Yup it doesn't seems to work on a `*.tex` file on my system.

Comment: @statox, thanks. I'll see if I can find some way to make it work for `*.tex` files too.

Comment: @Lawrence: I was digging the code of the plugin, I guess it is possible but so far I haven't found a solution.

Comment: @statox, how odd. I thought the normal extension for latex files were tex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that LaTeX-Box loads some of its function only when the filetype of the buffer is set to `tex`. On some systems `*.tex` files's filetype is set to `plaintext`.

You have two options:

- Renaming your files to `*.latex`
- Adding `autocmd! BufReadPost,BufNewFile *.tex set filetype=tex` to your `.vimrc` to set the proper filetype to your `*.tex` files.

Comment: The second option doesn't work for me. Nor did `let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'` which I had before.  `set filetype?` echos `tex`; but there is no `:Latexmk`.

Comment: @Lawrence: Ok that's really weird, I'll try to find another solution then

Comment: Yeah, did you reproduce it?  Maybe the decision whether or not to load latexmk.vim is made before the filetype is changed.

Comment: Yup I based my answer on my experimentation: on my system `*.tex` files's filetype was set to `plaintext` and `:Latexmk` wasn't available but the autocmd solved the problem.

Comment: I think I found out where the problem lies.  Your solution works when I load a tex file normally, with `vi a.tex`. But not when I load it through a list with `vi (backtick) cat toc (backtick).

Comment: That's probably because with this syntax Vim can't see which type of file you're editing... Maybe it would be worth to ask for help in another question :-)